# What happened to the fasting conspirators who sought to kill Paul?

Tags: acts, paul, curses

When Paul traveled to Jerusalem after his 3rd missionary journey there was quite a commotion and multiple attempts were made on his life.

After he was arrested, 40 men took an oath to eat nothing until they had killed him:

> 12 And when it was day, certain of the Jews banded together, and bound
> themselves under a curse, saying that they would neither eat nor drink
> till they had killed Paul.
>
> 13 And they were more than forty which had made this conspiracy.
>
> 14 And they came to the chief priests and elders, and said, We have
> bound ourselves under a great curse, that we will eat nothing until we
> have slain Paul. (Acts 23:12-14)

Well...their plot was discovered and Paul was escorted safely to the governor (see rest of chapter).

What happened to these conspirators?  Would they have abstained from food until they died or would they have broken the vow? What might have happened to them had they chosen to break the vow?

Comment: We are not told - they must have either broken their fast, or, starved to death.  But we do not know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gill offers this answer:

> saying, that they would neither eat nor drink till they had killed Paul: it was a common form of a vow or oath with the Jews (b),

(b) is an extra-biblical document: Misna Nedarim, c. 2. sect. 2, 3

> it may be asked, what became of this vow? or how did they get clear of it, since they did not accomplish the fact?

These are the questions of interest.

> to which it may be answered, that it was a **pretty easy thing to be freed** from oaths and vows, among the Jews, whose doctors had a power to absolve men from them;

There were learned Jews who were empowered to release them of their vow and they could do so in different ways. No problem.

> and in such cases as this, and such a vow as this, might be loosed upon more accounts than one, as on account of keeping another law, the observing the sabbath and other festivals, when men were obliged to eat and drink: and thus it is said (d),
>
> "if a man swears that he will not drink wine, or that he will not eat flesh, for so many days, then they say to him, if thou hadst known at the time of the oath, that the sabbath or a feast day were within these days, in which thou art obliged to eat flesh and drink wine, as it is said, Isaiah 58:13 "and call the sabbath a delight"; wouldst thou have swore at all? if he says no, they loose his oath:''

Sorry, I didn't know at the time that my vow would extend into the sabbath. Isaiah 58:13 overrides my vow.

Isaiah 58:13

> "If you keep your feet from breaking the Sabbath and from doing as you please on my holy day, if you call the Sabbath a delight and the LORD's holy day honorable, and if you honor it by not going your own way and not doing as you please or speaking idle words,

If the conspirators couldn't wait until the Sabbath, no problem:

> and likewise it might be loosed on account of life, which a man is bound to preserve: for so they likewise say (e),
>
> "if a man vows that he will not eat anything, woe be to him if he eats, and woe be to him if he does not eat; if he eats he breaks his vow, if he does not eat he sins against his own soul, or life; what must he do? let him go to the wise men, , "and **they will loose his vow for him**", as it is written, Proverbs 12:18 but the tongue of the wise is health;''

Proverbs 12:18 overrides the vows:

> The words of the reckless pierce like swords, but the tongue of the wise brings healing.

> and no doubt but these men very easily got their vow loosed, since it was made on such a design.
>
> (e) T. Hieros. Avoda Zara, fol. 40. 1.

Now, these extremists were no longer bound by their vows—until the next occasion, I guess. Then the cycle repeats. No problem. No wonder Jesus told the Jews in Matthew 5:

> 34But I tell you, **do not swear an oath** at all: either by heaven, for it is God’s throne; 35or by the earth, for it is his footstool; or by Jerusalem, for it is the city of the Great King. 36And do not swear by your head, for you cannot make even one hair white or black. 37All you need to say is simply ‘Yes’ or ‘No’; anything beyond this comes from the evil one.

Comment: Thank you for this very thorough response! And great connection to the sermon on the mount.